# Large volumn of concurrent test for websocket

Tags: websocket, benchmarking, stress-testing

I want to make a stress test to a websocket server. 
Expected to open 100k connnection.

I have two machine, A and B, B run the websocket, A run the test client.
For the port can be only open about 65535 - 1024, config by 
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024    65535

How to expand this range, any tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more IP addresses to your machine. You can have 65536 TCP ports open for each IP address you have.

If you're on some kind of Linux you should just be able to `ifconfig eth0:1 <ipaddress>`, `ifconfig eth0:2 <ipaddress2>`, and so on.

What tool are you using for generating Websocket traffic?  From what I know these tools can simulate Websocket clients:

- Jmeter: http://jmeter.apache.org
- Gatling: https://gatling.io
- Tsung: http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/
- k6: https://k6.io

Some of them might not do it natively, but need plugins. k6 (I'm involved in the k6 project) has it built in though.